# tornado get_secure_cookie returning not the same value that was set

Tags: python, tornado

all.

I have following problem with `set_secure_cookie/get_secure_cookie` functions. In a nutshell I am doing something like this:

```
username = 'user'
print(username)
self.set_secure_cookie('user', username)
print(self.get_secure_cookie('user'))
```

and the result is:

```
user
b'"user"'
```

What I can't understand is why initial and returned values differ. It's probably has to do something with escaping, but still I cannot catch the reason behind such behavior - typically when you use some Api to store a value you expect that you will retrieve the same value. Why this assumption is wrong in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason [`get_secure_cookie`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.get_secure_cookie) returns a bytestring instead of a unicode string (I suppose because it leaves it up to client to decide which encoding use). So for for utf-8 latin symbols you can get the initial string by running `tornado.escape.json_decode` on it.